# Hiding the Quick Time logo and controls when an audio file is played using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hai all,

in my application i need to play a streaming audio, i used MPMoviePlayerController to play the audio, it works fine, but i don't want the Logo and controls appearing on the screen( like playing in the background).

is there any way to hide the logo and controls ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the current Apple api.  If you want to use undocumented api's, you can always access the private methods.  Here is a good place to start looking:

[Erica Sadun's Core Dumps 1](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/%5Fm%5Fp%5Fmovie%5Fplayer%5Fcontroller%5F8h-source.html) 
[Erica Sadun's Core Dumps 2](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/%5Fm%5Fp%5Fmovie%5Fplayer%5Fcontroller%5Finternal%5F8h-source.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

[MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

or
[AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)